# Enumerations in C head files shared across multiple files

Tags: c, enums, header-files

I want to define an enumeration type ONCE and have that type be shared across all the other files when I include the file, however I keep getting the following errors:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 main.c invoc.h invoc.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘pr_alg’
main.c:12: error: ‘pr_alg’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:12: error: for each function it appears in.)
main.c:13: error: ‘FIFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
invoc.c:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘myalg’
```

The code is as follows:

`invoc.h`:

```
#define INVOC_H
#ifndef INVOC_H

typedef enum {FIFO, SECOND_CHANCE, RANDOM, NRU, CLOCK, AGING} alg_t;

void func1(alg_t myalg);

#endif
```

`invoc.c`:

```
#include "invoc.h"

void func1(alg_t myalg) {
    myalg = NRU;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "invoc.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    extern alg_t pr_alg;
    pr_alg = FIFO;
    printf("PR_ALG: %d\n", pr_alg);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way that I can define an enumeration in a .h file, and include it in all other files so that I can both create different variables of that type and pass it to functions?

Comment: You don't compile .h files, only .c files.

Comment: It still gives the same error when i dont compile with .h:        $ gcc -std=c99 main.c invoc.c -o main

Comment: In `invoc.h` you are defining `INVOC_H` before the `#ifndef INVOC_H` block. That is, it will never see the stuff inside the block.

Comment: D'oh, completely missed that. Thank you.

Comment: regarding: `void func1(alg_t myalg) {
    myalg = NRU;`   the assignment to `myalg` will only modify the local parameter (typically on the stack)  BTW: the function `funct1()` is never invoked.

Comment: regarding: `extern alg_t pr_alg;`  there is no instance of the enum `pr_alg` anywhere in the posted code.

Answer (score 12):

1. You have an error in your `invoc.h` file:

   ```
   #define INVOC_H
   #ifndef INVOC_H
   ...
   #endif
   ```

   You first define a macro `INVOC_H`, then check if it does not exists (it does), so the code inside is removed by the preprocessor and not parsed by the compiler.
   It should be:

   ```
   #ifndef INVOC_H
   #define INVOC_H
   ...
   #endif
   ```

   After this change your code will work fine.
2. You don't compile `.h` files, only `.c` files.  That's why we put all definitions in `.c` files, and only declarations in `.h` files. To compile, just do:

   ```
   gcc -std=c99 mmu.c invoc.c
   ```
3. You declare `pr_alg` in `main()` as `extern` variable. If the line you provided is the whole compilation line, the compile will issue linker error as variable `pr_alg` is nowhere defined. Remove `extern` or define variable `pr_alg` with global storage duration in one of the `.c` files.

Comment: I am pretty certain OP doesn't want a global variable.